# Java: Adding a boolean check method to check data from an sql table to copy to textfile

Tags: java, mysql, boolean, text-files

I am sorry for the bad phrasing of this question but here is where I am stucked at.

I have a database table which contains data about donors such as id, name, address, contact, age (of persons less or equal to 34 years old) and blood group.

I have to sort the data of the donors based their blood groups into two text files namely `APositive.txt` and `BNegative.txt` ie those with A+ blood group will have their data in the APositive.txt and the same goes for B- blood group. A boolean method `verifyAge(int, int)` should be used to verify the age of the person to be included in the text files.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public class Donor {

    public static boolean verifyAge(int age, int maxAge) {
        if (age <= maxAge) 
            return true;
        else 
            return false;
    }

    private static Formatter writeToFileFormatter;
    private static Formatter writeToFileFormatter1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            writeToFileFormatter = new Formatter("APositive.txt");
            writeToFileFormatter1 = new Formatter("BNegative.txt");
        }

        catch(SecurityException se) {
            System.out.println("Access Denied");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("Error creating file");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {

            Connection con = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/examques?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "admin");

            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from donor");

            while (rs.next()) {
                int id = rs.getInt("donor_id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String address = rs.getString("address");
                int tel = rs.getInt("tel");
                int age = rs.getInt("age");
                String blood_grp = rs.getString("blood_group");

                if (blood_grp.equals("A+")) {
                    writeToFileFormatter.format("Name: %s Address: %s Contact: %d Age: %d \n", name, address, tel, verifyAge(age, 34));
                }

                if (blood_grp.equals("B-")) {
                    writeToFileFormatter1.format("Name: %s Address: %s Contact: %d Age: %d \n", name, address, tel, verifyAge(age, 34));
                }
            }

            if (writeToFileFormatter != null) {
                writeToFileFormatter.close();
            }

            if (writeToFileFormatter1 != null) {
                writeToFileFormatter1.close();
            }

        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Below is a screenshot of the error I am getting:**

[image]

**EDIT:**

Thanks for all the answers

I have solved it this way:

```
if(blood_grp.equals("A+")&& verifyAge(age, 34)==true){    
    writeToFileFormatter.format("Name: %s Address: %s Contact: %d Age: %d \n", name, address, tel,age);
}

if(blood_grp.equals("B-")&&verifyAge(age, 34)==true){
    writeToFileFormatter1.format("Name: %s Address: %s Contact: %d Age: %d \n", name, address, tel, age);
}
```

Comment: @PeterMmm Line 61 is `writeToFileFormatter.format("Name: %s Address: %s Contact: %d Age: %d \n", name, address, tel, verifyAge(age, 34));`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `%d` for Age in your `"Name: %s Address: %s Contact: %d Age: %d \n"` string. So the last parameter is expected to be decimal, but your `verifyAge()` function returns `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
writeToFileFormatter.format("Name: %s Address: %s Contact: %d Age: %d \n", name, address, tel, verifyAge(age, 34)?1:0);
```

`%d` expects a number not a boolean.

Comment: Nope, this didn't work. It's only outputing 0 or 1 for Age. That is 1 for those   are eligible and 0 for who aren't. Like this: `Name: Mary Address: Ashton Rd Contact: 7654222 Age: 1 `
`Name: James Address: Reese Rd Contact: 7044222 Age: 0 `

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have solved it(check edited post)

Answer (score 0):

%d format is looking for a integer value but you are passing a boolean is the reason for that error.

If you want to print boolean value that is true or false. Please replace %d by %b

See this snippet below to fix that,

```
class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Test a1 = new Test();

    boolean a = false;
    boolean b = true;

    System.out.println(String.format("%b", a));
    System.out.println(String.format("%b", b));
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. But I want to print out the age, not true or false

Comment: Do you want to print age if only true? what do you want to print if false?

Comment: if false(that is age>34), the donor will not be accepted hence that donor's details will not go in any of the text files. Anyway, I have solved it(check edited post)

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: I am sorry but I couldn't do it that way since I had to print an integer not a boolean.